# JQuery issue using closest to find text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently am outputting two tables in each iteration of a foreach loop (c# razor view although that isn't too relevant here). I wrap these two tables in a div with class = `jq-roundContainer` and each input in both tables has class `jq-hitOrMiss`. I am trying to sum up the number of X's entered into the text inputs as follows but variable `sum` is 0 (when I know it shouldnt be) and `inputs.length` is 0 also. html and simple jquery function below

html:

```
<div class="jq-roundContainer">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="active">
                <th colspan="2" class="text-center">1</th>
                <th colspan="2" class="text-center">2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none">
                    @Html.Hidden("EventId", Request.Params["eventId"]);
                    @Html.Hidden("UserId", Request.Params["userId"]);
                    <input type="hidden" name="scoreCards[@i].UserProfile" value="@round.UserProfile" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="jq-hitOrMiss" onchange="SumHits();" name="scoreCards[@i].Hit1StationOneShotOne" pattern="[xXoO]" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit1StationOneShotOne)" />
                </td>                                

                @{i++;}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="active">
                <th colspan="2" class="text-center">14</th>
                <th class="text-center">TOTAL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="jq-hitOrMiss" onchange="SumHits();" name="scoreCards[@i].Hit27StationThreeShotSeven" pattern="[xXoO]" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit27StationThreeShotSeven)" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center total jq-total">@round.Score</td>
                @{i++;}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and jquery function:

```
 function SumHits() {

        var sum = 0;
        var inputs = $(this).closest('.jq-roundContainer').find('.jq-hitOrMiss');
        $.each(inputs, function (index, value) {
            var value = $(value).val();
            if (value == 'X' || value == 'x') {
                sum++;
            }
        });
        var totalInput = $(this).closest('.jq-roundContainer').find('.jq-total');
        totalInput.text(sum);
    }
```

Comment: Try to console.log the value of this, and check if it refers to your input element

Comment: You need to pass the reference to the function, as `onchange="SumHits(this);"`. Just one note: you should use jQuery better, there is no need to define onchange functions inline for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside normal function this will points to `window`. So when you are using an inline handler, you have to pass the `this` explicitly, receive it inside the function and use it.

```
function SumHits(_this) {
  var inputs = $(_this).closest('.jq-roun.....
```

And in html,

```
<input class="jq-hitOrMiss" onchange="SumHits(this);".....
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem arise to the `this` element which refers to `window` not the element which triggered the event. Thus you are getting the result

As you are using jQuery bind event using it like and get rid of ulgy inline-click handler.

```
$('.jq-hitOrMiss').on('change', SumHits)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, remove the on change on your html it is difficult to maintain

```
$('div.jq-roundContainer input.jq-hitOrMiss').change(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('.jq-roundContainer');
    var sum = 0;
    var inputs = $parent.find('.jq-hitOrMiss');
    inputs.each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'X' || value == 'x') {
            sum++;
        }
    });
    var totalInput = $parent.find('.jq-total');
    totalInput.text(sum);
});
```

or if you want to keep your function

```
$('div.jq-roundContainer input.jq-hitOrMiss').change(SumHits);

function SumHits(){
    var $parent = $(this).parents('.jq-roundContainer');
    var sum = 0;
    var inputs = $parent.find('.jq-hitOrMiss');
    inputs.each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'X' || value == 'x') {
            sum++;
        }
    });
    var totalInput = $parent.find('.jq-total');
    totalInput.text(sum);
}
```